# Can't remove files from remote repository

Tags: git, git-commit, git-remote, git-add

I deleted some files from my local repository, and when I type git status it says they have been deleted but when I try to add them it says that they did not match any files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
git add -u <filename>
```